# batch script for running application on two machines @homenetwork

Tags: batch-file, remote-access, process.start

I am trying figure out how to run an application on local pc and then on my second pc both are at my home network,  I am using several applications which merge together by entering second pc ip, so i though if i can anyway do something like

---

my spec: local 10.0.0.1
and second pc 10.0.0.4

need to run from my local

---

@echo off

start "" "C:\TEST\TESTAPP.EXE"

start 10.0.0.4 "C:\TEST2\TESTAPP.EXE"  <-- just need find a way how to do this

didnt found anything regarding start command and ip address specified maybe it couldnt be achieved with bat script?

thanks everyone for any helpful response and sorry if its just dumb question

Comment: Just to clarify, you're trying to run an application on another PC on the same network by using its IP address?

Comment: yes i want to stream keypunch for second machine using specific app, already set and prepared my own script, which working just fine, but still have to run streamingkeys app on pc1 and then on pc2 which i wanted to automatized via some script started from pc1

Comment: What you're trying to do will run both apps on your local PC, but the second app would be retrieved from the second PC into memory on your local PC and executed there. You need to look into `rexec` - a search here or via Google/Bing should locate info for you.

Comment: well regarding UAC feature which i wont to disable and for compatibility with other users, its will be just enough to open folder path with installed application on second machine via script running from fist machine

Comment: there are two machines A and B and i want open folder on B machine from A machine and wrap it into script(previously it was execute an app but not anymore)

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly you are trying to start a script on machine B from machine A. If this is correct I would recommend using [PSExec](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb897553.aspx) from [Sysinternals Suit](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb842062.aspx).

Example

```
Psexec.exe \\<computername or ip> -u username -p password C:\ProgramToRun.exe
```

PSExec help file from http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb897553.aspx

```
Using PsExec

Usage: psexec [\\computer[,computer2[,...] | @file]][-u user [-p psswd][-n s][-r servicename][-h][-l][-s|-e][-x][-i [session]][-c [-f|-v]][-w directory][-d][-<priority>][-a n,n,...] cmd [arguments]
-a  Separate processors on which the application can run with commas where 1 is the lowest numbered CPU. For example, to run the application on CPU 2 and CPU 4, enter: "-a 2,4"
-c  Copy the specified program to the remote system for execution. If you omit this option the application must be in the system path on the remote system.
-d  Don't wait for process to terminate (non-interactive).
-e  Does not load the specified account’s profile.
-f  Copy the specified program even if the file already exists on the remote system.
-i  Run the program so that it interacts with the desktop of the specified session on the remote system. If no session is specified the process runs in the console session.
-h  If the target system is Vista or higher, has the process run with the account's elevated token, if available.
-l  Run process as limited user (strips the Administrators group and allows only privileges assigned to the Users group). On Windows Vista the process runs with Low Integrity.
-n  Specifies timeout in seconds connecting to remote computers.
-p  Specifies optional password for user name. If you omit this you will be prompted to enter a hidden password.
-r  Specifies the name of the remote service to create or interact with.
-s  Run the remote process in the System account.
-u  Specifies optional user name for login to remote computer.
-v  Copy the specified file only if it has a higher version number or is newer on than the one on the remote system.
-w  Set the working directory of the process (relative to remote computer).
-x  Display the UI on the Winlogon secure desktop (local system only).
-priority   Specifies -low, -belownormal, -abovenormal, -high or -realtime to run the process at a different priority. Use -background to run at low memory and I/O priority on Vista.
computer    Direct PsExec to run the application on the remote computer or computers specified. If you omit the computer name, PsExec runs the application on the local system, and if you specify a wildcard (\\*), PsExec runs the command on all computers in the current domain.
@file   PsExec will execute the command on each of the computers listed in the file.
cmd Name of application to execute.
arguments   Arguments to pass (note that file paths must be absolute paths on the target system).
-accepteula This flag suppresses the display of the license dialog.
```